# Cell factory для вариативных Property

Tags: java, javafx, binding, tableview

В классе-модели имеются два вида `Property`: `SimpleStringProperty` и `SimpleIntegerProperty`. Необходимо их отобразить в виде `TableView`, где первая колонка - имя значения (описание), а вторая само значение. Что-то типа этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные класса-модели упаковываются в `Map<String,Property<?>>`, где key - имя значения, а value - `Property` со значением.

Интересует следующее:

1) Каким образом должна выглядеть CellValueFactory, чтобы значения были корректно "забиндены", т.е. в случае необходимости их можно было бы изменить в таблице и изменения отразились в классе-модели.

2) Правильно ли оформлены дженерики в мапе-упаковке?

**UPD:** Добавил промежуточный класс для решения данного вопроса, однако считаю, что получился "костыль":

```
public class PropertiesContainer {
    private String propName;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty concreteIntSourceProperty=null;
    private SimpleStringProperty concreteStrSourceProperty=null;
    private SimpleStringProperty destProperty;

    public PropertiesContainer(String propName, Property<?> property) {
        this.propName = propName;
        if (property.getClass().equals(SimpleStringProperty.class)){
            concreteStrSourceProperty = (SimpleStringProperty) property;
            destProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(concreteStrSourceProperty.get());
        }
        else if (property.getClass().equals(SimpleIntegerProperty.class)) {
            concreteIntSourceProperty = (SimpleIntegerProperty) property;
            destProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(Integer.toString(concreteIntSourceProperty.get()));
        }

        destProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (concreteIntSourceProperty!=null) concreteIntSourceProperty.set(Integer.valueOf(newValue));
            else concreteStrSourceProperty.set(newValue);
        });
    }
    public String getDestProperty() {
        return destProperty.get();
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty destProperty() {
        return destProperty;
    }
    public String getPropName() {
        return propName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну с расширенного мной примера из [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm):

```
public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    public static final String Column1MapKey = "String";
    public static final String Column2MapKey = "Integer";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("TODO List");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        TableColumn<Map, String> firstDataColumn = new TableColumn<>("Description");
        TableColumn<Map, String> secondDataColumn = new TableColumn<>("Value");

        firstDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Column1MapKey));
        firstDataColumn.setMinWidth(130);
        secondDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Column2MapKey));
        secondDataColumn.setMinWidth(130);

        TableView table_view = new TableView<>(generateDataInMap());

        table_view.setEditable(true);
        table_view.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table_view.getColumns().setAll(firstDataColumn, secondDataColumn);

        firstDataColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>, TableCell<Map, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                return new TextFieldTableCell(new DefaultStringConverter());
            }
        });

        secondDataColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>, TableCell<Map, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                return new TextFieldTableCell(new IntegerStringConverter());
            }
        });

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();

        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table_view);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<Map> generateDataInMap() {
        int max = 10;
        ObservableList<Map> allData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {

            Map<String, Property<?>> dataRow = new HashMap<>();

            SimpleStringProperty value1 = new SimpleStringProperty("string " + i);
            SimpleIntegerProperty value2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(i);

            dataRow.put(Column1MapKey, value1);
            dataRow.put(Column2MapKey, value2);

            allData.add(dataRow);
        }
        return allData;
    }
}
```

Ну и по пунктам вопроса:

Обратите внимание метод CellValueFactory - заполняет ячейки а вот за динамическое изменение отвечает метод setCellFactory - который через длинную цепочку оберток отвечает за взаимодействие с Property объектом - к слову в оригинальном примере показана работа с реализацией абстрактного класса StringConverter - отличный выход из многих ситуаций.

Да - замечательный дженерик.

UPD:
Как пример работы с SimpleObjectProperty

класс обертка:

```
class Wrapper {

    class InnerWrapper<T> extends SimpleObjectProperty<T> {

        @Override
        public void set(T newValue) {
            T temp = null;
            if (newValue.getClass().equals(Integer.class))
                temp = newValue;
            else
                temp = (T) (((String) newValue).matches("\\d+") ? Integer.valueOf((String) newValue) : newValue.toString());
            super.set(temp);
        }

    }

    private InnerWrapper inner = new InnerWrapper();

    public Object getNut() {
        return nutProperty().get();
    }

    public final SimpleObjectProperty nutProperty() {
        return inner;
    }

    public void setNut(Object candiate) {
        nutProperty().set(candiate);
    }

}
```

пример фабрики:

```
    firstDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Map, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
         public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Map, String> p) {
             return ((Wrapper)p.getValue().get(Column1MapKey)).nutProperty();
         }
      });
```

Comment: Ваш пример работает, но не так, как нужно. Результатом является то, что в первой колонке всегда String значение ("string 1","string2"...), а вот второй только численное значение (1,2,3...). Мне, в свою очередь нужно, чтобы во второй колонке могли быть и String и Integer значения и их можно было бы забиндить и редактировать. Я в, общем ситуацию решил, но довольно коряво: ввел промежуточный объект с двумя Property. Первый исходный, второй для передачи в таблицу. На втором висит слушатель, который при изменении значения меняет соотв. в первом Property

Comment: Ясно да попахивает костылем.К слову а почему вы не использовали SimpleObjectProperty<Object>? считайте универсальный контейнер и меньше кода...?Точно такая-же оболочка и проверку/приведение типов в ней реализовать стоит

Comment: Если не сложно, могли бы вы показать пример использования SimpleObjectProperty, а то я так и не разобрался с ним

Comment: Да конечно приведу.только разъясните что именно не понятно?По своей сути он абсолютно не отличается от всех остальных типов  Property хранит любой тип объектов расширяет абстрактный класс ObjectPropertyBase<T> тот в своею очередь расширяет реализацию ObjectProperty<T> на пол пути к суперклассу Object вешает слушателей на наблюдаемый объект имплементируя Observable

Comment: Мне не понятна инициализация TableView для данного случая и где проверка/приведение должна осуществляться.

Comment: Пример дополнил

Comment: Если не затруднит, объясните пожалуйста, каким образом при приведении ко `Wrapper`'у сохранится биндинг в обе стороны, ведь класс объекта меняется, а проперти не наследуются от simpleObject ?

Comment: Wrapper это класс обертка предоставляющий доступ к объекту расширяющему функционал класса  SimpleObjectProperty c переопределенным методом set() - т.е с точки зрения связей абсолютно релевантная система. Wrapper - это промежуточное звено с описанными согласно договоренностями методами.